# Depth First Search With 1 cycle Print

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

My Depth First search works perfectly but it does not deal with Cycles. I want to print one cycle too with the DFS.

`printAllPaths(VertexA, VertexC)` would result in something like this:

```
A B C D C //with cycle since C repeated
A B C 
A D C 
A D E B C 
A E B C
```

The code is below

```
  void printAllPathsUtil(Vertex v, Vertex d, ArrayList<Vertex> path){

        v.state = VISITED;
        path.add(v);

        if (v == d) {
            for (Vertex p : path) {
                System.out.print("Print: " + p.value + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            for (Vertex city : v.outboundCity){

                if (city.state == UNVISITED) {

                    printAllPathsUtil(city, d, path);
                }
            }
        }
        path.remove(v);
        v.state = UNVISITED;
    }


    void printAllPaths(Vertex v, Vertex u){
        clearStates();
        ArrayList<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<>();
        printAllPathsUtil(v, u, path);
    }
```

Vertex Class is something like this:

```
public class Vertex{
String value;

Vertex previous = null;
int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

List<Vertex> inboundCity;
List<Vertex> outboundCity;
State state;
}
```

I know we should not have a case where it prints infinitely. But it should only print 1 cycle. I have tried many things but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

So from the above code I feel you have a nice understanding about how graphs work.

So the above method would print all the paths in graph. Let that method stay as it is.

For the purpose of finding a cycle in a graph, you can create a new method that simply finds a cycle for you.

Here is the pseudo code for it, I haven't run it so I cannot so it's completely correct but you will get the idea for sure

```
ArrayList<Vertex> dfsCycle(Vertex v, ArrayList<Vertex> path) {
 if(v.state = VISITED) {
   System.out.println("Yayy found a cycle");
  return path;
 }
 path.add(v);
 for(Vertex city : v.outboundCity) {
   dfsCycle(city,path);
 }
 return path;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is correct. The problem is the implementation of State. The condition in "if (city.state == UNVISITED)" is true, only if city.state and UNVISITED are the same class. If city.state and UNVISITED are of the primitive type int, the algorithm works fine.

```
 public enum State {
    VISITED (1),
    UNVISITED (2);

    private final int state;

    State(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return this.state;
    }
}
```

And now: `if(city.state.getState() == State.UNVISTED.getState()) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow exactly one cycle then use `0,1,2` instead of `state.VISITED` and `state.UNVISITED`

instead of `v.state = VISITED` use `v.state++`
instead of `v.state = UNVISITED` use `v.state--`
instead of `if(city.state == UNVISITED)` use `if(city.state < 2)`

By increasing the value in the last condition you can also set the number of allowed cycles.

Actually it allows the algorithm to access all cities twice instead of one, so if the map has multiple cycles then there could be multiple cycles in the calculated routes but a given city can be visited at max twice in each route.

And one more thing: You also have to provide the last station to the method and exclude it in the loop otherwise there will be tons of mini-cycles in the solution like ABABC, ABCBC

Eh, here is the whole code:

```
 void printAllPathsUtil(Vertex prev, Vertex v, Vertex d, ArrayList<Vertex> path){

        v.state++;
        path.add(v);

        if (v == d) {
            for (Vertex p : path) {
                System.out.print("Print: " + p.value + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            for (Vertex city : v.outboundCity){

                if (city!= prev && city.state < 2) {

                    printAllPathsUtil(v, city, d, path);
                }
            }
        }
        path.remove(v);
        v.state--;
    }


    void printAllPaths(Vertex v, Vertex u){
        clearStates();
        ArrayList<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<>();
        printAllPathsUtil(null, v, u, path);
    }
```